# Codeigniter user tracking for visitors

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-tracking

I am working on Codeigniter site and trying to implement **User tracking functionality for visitors** only (not registered users).

I want to track ( ip address, from_page, to_page, time_stamp) on every page redirect and as I want to track only temporary users I would need to access database too, to check whether account exists or not.

My question is where to write my code, so that Codeigniter automatically checks before each redirect, (keep in mind, that place should have rights to access database or sessions).

Checking in each controller file will make so much redundant code and I don't think htaccess file could do it .

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

One is to create a helper file, say `trackuser_helper.php` in the helpers folder. Create a function to do the tracking in this file (say `trackUser()`). Then autoload this file inside `config/autoload.php`like so:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Helper Files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
*/

$autoload['helper'] = array('trackuser'); //ignore the '_helper.php' portion of the filename
```

Now you can just call `trackUser()` in every controller.

The second option which in my opinion is better is to use `Hooks` provided by `CodeIgniter`

These are defined inside `config/hooks.php` like so:

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MyClass',
                                'function' => 'Myfunction',
                                'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array('param1', 'param2', 'etc')
                                );
```

The array index correlates to the name of the particular hook point you want to use. In the above example the hook point is pre_controller. A list of hook points is found below. The following items should be defined in your associative hook array:

1.Class - The name of the class you wish to invoke. If you prefer to use
   a procedural function instead of a class, leave this item blank.

2.Function - The function name you wish to call. filename  The file name
   containing your class/function.

3.Filepath - The name of the directory
   containing your script. Note: Your script must be located in a
   directory INSIDE your application folder, so the file path is
   relative to that folder. For example, if your script is located in
   application/hooks, you will simply use hooks as your filepath. If
   your script is located in application/hooks/utilities you will use
   hooks/utilities as your filepath. No trailing slash.

4.Params - Any parameters you wish to pass to your script. 
   This item is optional.

This specifies which function call you want to execute before each controller load. This way you do not even need to add `trackuser()` to each `controller`. These hooks can be `pre_controller` or `post_controller`. You can read more about hooks at the [CI documentation.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but for every redirect I would have to call this function in each function of every controller, and as a result registered users will also face some delay

Comment: @hass_ I have updated the answer with another option which uses hooks. Also for every redirect you do, you do not need to call it in each function of the controller, just inside the constructor will do.

Comment: thanks thats perfect, One more thing after redirected to the function through hook I can get current url through current_url(), how can I get the requested url, any idea?

Comment: Well if somebody needs it, here is an option 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984234/get-the-requested-controller-in-hook-precontroller-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks really helpful